# Bayes' theorem having true and false positive on different events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

> Wire manufactured by a company is tested for strength. The test gives
>   a correct positive result with a probability of 0.85 when the wire is
>   strong, but gives an incorrect positive result (false positive) with a
>   probability of 0.04 when in fact the wire is not strong.
>
> If 98% of the wires are strong, and a wire chosen at random fails the
>   test, what is the probability it really is not strong enough?

I am just newbie to probability math but want to solve it, can any tell me what all events are given from this? And how to identify them?

I found out that I am having trouble in finding events, if I find them, rest is easy.

Comment: There are four events:  either the wire is strong and tests strong, it is strong and tests weak, it is weak and tests strong, it is weak and tests weak.

Comment: But using that I am unable to find answer

Comment: Well, what goes wrong when you just follow the standard methods?

Comment: I am unable to get all values. I am just using single formula which I am aware of

P(A1|S) = (P(A1) x P(S|A1)) / (P(A1) x P(S|A1)) + (P(A2) x P(S|A2)).

A1 consider it as true positive, A2 as false positive and S as strong wire

Comment: I think this link might help me to understand that problem- http://onlinestatbook.com/2/probability/bayes_demo.html

Comment: @lulu thanks for encouraging... Understood my problem area. Using above link was able to solve it using P(S|T) = (P(T|S) x P(S)) / [(P(T|S) x P(S)) + (P(T|S') x P(S'))]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events -
Strong wire P(S)
Weak Wire P(S')
Result = P(T) - true positive result

P(S) = 0.98
P(S') = 0.02
P(T|S) = 0.85
P(T|S') = 0.04

> P(S|T) = (P(T|S) x P(S)) / [(P(T|S) x P(S)) + (P(T|S') x P(S'))]

P(S|T) = 0.85 x 0.98 / (0.85 x 0.98 + 0.04 x 0.02) = 0.8673 / 0.8681 = 0.9991 = 99.91%

99.91% times wires are strong when tested positive

For wires tested strong and result is weak = 1 - P(S|T) = 1 - 0.99 = 0.01 = 1%
So, a wire chosen from suite of strong tested wire and comes out to be weak is 1%